# wordpress website super slow on chinese hosting

Tags: wordpress, slowdown, performance

I have a problem with the hosting of my client,

My wordpress website is really slow on their hosting, compare to my own hosting,

I've been deleting all images not use and plugin, it doesnt change anything . . .

you can see on this link the test of the speed, it's really terrible. IS there anyway to change this ?

http://postimg.org/image/suxegjj4d/

Thank you so much

Comment: Is it slow for people in China too? Are they the audience?

Comment: yes it is too . ..  they are the audience exactly

Comment: 1. Why are you censoring the URL? 2. You didn't successfully censor the URL. http://vinacotheque.com/?post_type=product is indeed slow for me but certainly not 15 seconds to initial connection...

Answer (score 1):

Fairly simple: tell your client they need a new webhost.